# How to I get session value in function.php in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, session

Here I attached my function.php code

> ```
> add_action('paypal_ipn_for_wordpress_payment_status_completed','process_payment', 10, 1);
> function process_payment( $posted )
> {    
> $email12= $_SESSION['email12'];
> $id1=$_SESSION['id'];
> $date=$_SESSION['date'];
> // Parse data from IPN $posted[] array
> $first_name = isset($posted['first_name']) ? $posted['first_name'] : '';
> $last_name = isset($posted['last_name']) ? $posted['last_name'] : '';
> $payment_amount = isset($posted['mc_gross']) ? $posted['mc_gross'] : '';
> $recurring_payment_id = isset($posted['recurring_payment_id']) ? $posted['recurring_payment_id'] : '';
> $payer_email = isset($posted['payer_email']) ? $posted['payer_email'] : '';
> $txn_id = isset($posted['txn_id']) ? $posted['txn_id'] : '';
> $receiver_email= isset($posted['receiver_email']) ? $posted['receiver_email'] : '';   
>     $mail_From    = $payer_email;
>     $mail_To      = $receiver_email;
> $mail_Subject = "VERIFIED IPN";
>     $mail_Body    = "Hello Secretary,
>                  New registration for the event: 
>                      Name: $first_name $last_name";
>  mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);   
> $mail_From    = $receiver_email;
>     $mail_To      = $payer_email;
>     $mail_Subject = "VERIFIED IPN";
>     $mail_Body    = "Thank you for registration. Your registration has been successfully done.";
> mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);                                                              require_once('wp-config.php');
>  global $wpdb;                  
> $id12 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_nonmembersdetail where Email= '$email12'  ");
> foreach($id12 as $row1)
>  {
> $wpdb->insert( wp_checkoutnonmembersdetails, array( 
>                             'Event_Name' => $row1->Event_Name,
>             'First_Name' => $row1->First_Name,
>             'Last_Name' => $row1->Last_Name, 
>             'Address' => $row1->Address, 
>             'Email' => $row1->Email, 
>             'cellphone' => $row1->cellphone, 
>             'quantity' => $row1->quantity,
>                             'payment_amount' => $payment_amount
>     ) );
>  }  
> $id22 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_tmpmembersdetail where  id = '$id1' ");
> foreach($id22 as $row2)
> {
> $wpdb->insert( wp_checkouttmpmembersdetail, array( 
>                             'Event_Name' => $row2->Event_Name,
>             'First_Name' => $row2->First_Name,
>             'Last_Name' => $row2->Last_Name, 
>             'Address' => $row2->Address, 
>             'Email' => $row2->Email, 
>             'cellphone' => $row2->cellphone, 
>             'quantity' => $row2->quantity,
>                             'payment_amount' => $payment_amount
>     ) );
>     }}
> ```

I found that there is no proble in function.php I think there is a problem in IPN hook. bcz I already get session value in my another hook code which is also in function.php and also working perfectly. Above I attached IPN hook code. In that I want to get session value of email12. please anyone help me.

Comment: Have you started the session?

Comment: It looks like you already are doing that.... `$email12 = $_SESSION["email12"];`

Comment: I try with  started session  and without start session.

Comment: ya above code I try it

Comment: In which file you are doing this? I don't see any `session_start()`.

Comment: @b0s3 I edit my code please check it again. I wrote this code in function.php file

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION)` and check you it prints.

Comment: If you have set the session variable `$_SESSION['email12']` earlier, perhaps in a different page, you should be able to fetch or assign its value to a variable like this `$var = $_SESSION['email12']`.
I see you have already done it in your code, try `print_r($_SESSION)`, see what that gives.

Comment: some time session problem occur in wordpress, so you must need to call session_start(); function on both files like function.php and other file, where you have assign value to session.

Comment: Actually I didnt get print value bcz of i wrote in function.php file

Comment: @Dilipkumar I also call session_start(); both side.

Comment: try this code in function.php file.                                                                 `function sess_start() {
    if (!session_id())
    session_start();
}
add_action('init','sess_start');`

Comment: @Dilipkumar Hey please tell me where i put this code. I mean in my que code where I write down your code. please help me. I m beginner of wordpress.

Comment: at top in function.php file.

Comment: I added this code still not working

Comment: is anywhere I used sess_start function. bcz this code I add but how it work to pass session is it hook??

Comment: I found problem at which place. In my code I get another session value in function.php and also work properly. I think problem in IPN hook in that I wrote my question code. I attached my whole code in question please refer again and help me. its so urgent for me. please help me